# Is it possible to load a openlaszlo swf 10 runtime component in DHTML runtime?

Tags: openlaszlo, lzx

I am having a audio recorder component which is currently in swf 10 environment. This uses the microphone activity level and other microphone api's while recording the audio. I am currently converting the application to dhtml runtime. Is it possible to use a swf 10 component in dhtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLaszlo has an example application doing exactly that: The [musicdhtml application](http://labs.openlaszlo.org/trunk-nightly/examples/musicdhtml/), here is the [link to the source code in SVN](http://svn.openlaszlo.org/openlaszlo/trunk/examples/musicdhtml/).

You have to create a 2nd OpenLaszlo SWF application, and embed that into the HTML page - as it's shown in [the JSP page](http://svn.openlaszlo.org/openlaszlo/trunk/examples/musicdhtml/index.jsp) for the *musicdhtml* example.

```
lz.embed.swf({url: 'audiokernel.lzx?lzt=swf', bgcolor: '#eaeaea', width: '0', height: '0', id: 'audiokernel'});
lz.embed.dhtml({url: 'main.lzx?lzt=object&lzr=dhtml&_canvas_debug=false', bgcolor: '#ffffff', width: '100%', height: '150', id: 'lzdhtmlapp'});
```

As you can see, the audiokernel.lzx has a width and height set to 0, is therefore invisible. Integration of both applications is achieved by calling `lz.embed.audiokernel.callMethod()` out of the SWF application, and by using `lz.Browser.callJS()` in the DHTML app.

Here is the play button in audioplayer.lzx, showing how the play method of the audioplayer is called when the button is clicked:

```
<button width="40" height="22" 
        onclick="lz.embed.audiokernel.callMethod('audioplayer.play()')" >
```

And the `onframe` handler in the audioplayer.lzx:

```
<handler name="onframe" args="f">
    //Debug.write("Got frame", f);
    lz.Browser.callJS('setCanAttr', null, 'frame', f); 
</handler>
```

Using `lz.Browser.callJS()` you can call any method in your DHTML application out of an SWF runtime app directly. The DHTML `canvas` is defined as a global var (not a very good practice) in the JavaScript namespace. Any element with an ID you set on a view in DHTML can  be target when using `lz.Browser.callJS()`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the musicdhtml example application, that's good to know.